# Angular js stop propagation from Bootstrap "dropdown-toggle" event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angular JS 1.3 app.

In it I have a table row repeater with an ng-click:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="user in users.users" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails">
 <!-- main row, with the menu td shown below -->
<tr class="row-details" ng-show="showDetails" ng-class="{ 'active': showDetails }">
    <td>this is the row that hows details</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

Which toggles opening a detail view. Works fine.  But now I need to add another item in each of the `td`s, a Bootstrap button menu:

```
<td>
<div class="btn-group">
  <div ng-switch on="user.status">
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-gear dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" ng-switch-when="Inactive">
        <li><a href="" ng-click="users.modals.deleteUser()">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" ng-switch-when="Invited">
        <li><a href="" ng-click="users.toast.resendInvite()">Resend invitation</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="users.modals.deleteUser()">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" ng-switch-default>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="users.toast.sentPassword()">Reset password</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="users.modals.deleteUser()">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Problem is, trying to click on this menu button instead triggers the ng-click on the row, toggling the row state but never opening my menu.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: Every td has menu buttons?

Comment: yes. it was decided that in addition to being able to toggle open the details of the table row, there was to be a "quick menu" to perform some actions directly.

Comment: Can you provide more code for td elements and dropdown menu?

Comment: I fleshed out my question with more of the code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is pretty tricky problem. The thing is that when you click menu button two things happens: the first is that it opens Bootstrap dropdown menu, and the second is that event propagates to the parent element and also triggers `showDetails = !showDetails`.

The obvious solution is to try to stop event propagation with `$event.stopPropagation()` on the `td` level, so that event doesn't bubble up the DOM tree and never triggers parent `ngClick`. Unfortunately, it will not work because Bootstrap sets up click event listener on the `document` element to benefit from bubbling, so you can't stop propagation.

The simplest solution I came up with in such cases is to set a flag on the original event object whether event occurred on the menu button. If this is the case `ngClick` on the `tr` won't do anything.

It will look like this for `tr`:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="user in users.users" ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown || (showDetails = !showDetails)">
```

ans for `button`:

```
<button ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown = true" class="btn btn-link btn-gear dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
</button>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/eIn6VW3Y2jHn0MtJQVcU?p=preview

Comment: Genius.  That's very clever.  I never would have guesses, thanks.

Comment: You my friend are a genius! This is exactly what I needed and a very simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

With help of dfsq's answer I managed solve same kind of problem in Angular 2. Here is my sample code.

```
<td class="tablerowdata" (click)="$event.dropdown || onSelect(track)" >

<button (click)="$event.dropdown = true" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle trackbuttons" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
```