# Bootstrap Select Not Opening On Click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have a dynamically created set of bootstrap-select widgets I'm making with a dropdown. My issue is that to have the select not close the dropdown I have to put a 'event.stopPropagation()' on the dropdown itself.

When I do this the bootstrap select doesn't open when clicked, but a normal select will work. Is there a way to get the bootstrap select to work within a bootstrap dropdown where stopPropagation() is called on the dropdown click event?

Edit:

Example JsFiddle Test App
https://jsfiddle.net/ChaseRLewisAlamode/r4k5cy9s/1/

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Manage Statuses <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="status-dropdown dropdown-menu" role='menu'>
         <li role='presentation'>
           <div class='status-item'>
               <div class='status-text'>My Status</div>
               <select class='selectpicker'>                                        
                  <option value='active' selected>Active</option>
                  <option value='pending'>Pending</option>
                  <option value='sold'>Sold</option>
                  <option value='inactive'>Inactive</option>
               </select>
            </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
 </div>
<div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Always Visible <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
       <ul class="visible-dropdown dropdown-menu" role='menu' style="display: block;">
         <li role='presentation'>
           <div class='status-item'>
               <div class='status-text'>My Status</div>
               <select class='selectpicker'>                                        
                  <option value='active' selected>Active</option>
                  <option value='pending'>Pending</option>
                  <option value='sold'>Sold</option>
                  <option value='inactive'>Inactive</option>
               </select>
            </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

javascript

```
$(".status-dropdown").on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'd recommend reading this question that is very similar.**

[Angular js stop propagation from Bootstrap "dropdown-toggle" event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292568/angular-js-stop-propagation-from-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle-event)

Since you didn't post any code, I'm assuming that your problem is fairly similar. If my answer is way off base, you could help me refine it by posting in-code examples of the phenomenon you're curious about.

For your benefit, I'll try paraphrasing it here:

---

When you click select, I predict that two things happen.

First is that it opens Bootstrap dropdown menu. Second, the event propagates to the parent element and also triggers something like 'showDetails = !showDetails'.

The obvious solution is to try to stop event propagation with $event.stopPropagation() on the td level, so that event doesn't bubble up the DOM tree and never triggers parent ngClick. Unfortunately, it will not work because Bootstrap sets up click event listener on the document element to benefit from bubbling, so you can't stop propagation.

---

Assuming that's what's happening, I'd recommend that you [check this example out](http://jsfiddle.net/UTYma/4/):

**Javascript:**

```
$("#orgchart").jOrgChart({ chartElement: '#chart' });

$("div#chart div.btn-group > a.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-menu li a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(.'dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart">
</div>

<ul id="orgchart" style="display:none;">
    <li>Test
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Actions
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="text-align:left;">
                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>Test1.1</li>
            <li>Test1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Apologize this answer is a bit backwards. I'm already using this method to prevent the dropdown itself from closing, my issue is that the bootstrap-select dropdowns don't work with this method. I can't even programmaticly trigger them for some reason using 'selectpicker('toggle')'. If I remove the stopPropagation and make the dropdown always visible, they work fine (naturally just a test case).

Comment: Would you be willing to post some code for me to look at?

Comment: Also, apologies for the misunderstanding. If I'm hearing you clearly, you're saying that the dropdown will open and close correctly, but while it's doing that, you're unable to get the correct reaction when you click on the options within the dropdown, correct? Like you can cause the menu to open, but clicking 'edit' (for example), will do nothing?

Comment: Yeah probably take me 30 min or so, as I'll have to write a sample to break it out of my current application since it is mostly dynamically generated. I'll create a small static example.

Yes, the bootstrap-select dropdowns that are sub elements of another dropdown don't show when I use stopPropagation(), If I don't use stopPropagation() trying to open the submenu closes the parent dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this later tonight if there is still no answer!